# Django: efficiently saving ManyToMany objects

Tags: python, django, orm, many-to-many, manytomanyfield

I have got a Stop model and a Service model. They form a ManyToMany relationship with each other.
This is done by using `stops = models.ManyToManyField(Stop, related_name='services')` inside the Service model.

I would like to create new services and stops while making as few queries as possible. Currently, this is how I do it:

1. Create all new services using `bulk_create`
2. Create all new stops using `bulk_create`
3. Retrieve all services from the database
4. Retrieve all stops from the database
5. Add the appropriate stops to each service

In this way, step 5 will produce as many queries as the number of services.

Is there a simpler way of saving ManyToMany relationships? Also, could I spare retrieving all services and stops right after creating them?

Service:

```
class Service(models.Model):

    # Many to many relationship with Stop
    stops = models.ManyToManyField(Stop, related_name='services')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=False, unique=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
```

Stop:

```
class Stop(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, unique=True)
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()
```

Comment: please show us your models.

Comment: Updated the question with the models.